# C++ while loop and string length

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

If I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
std::string str;
while (std::cin>>str)
std::cout<<str<<"\n"; 
std::cout<<str.length(); // UPDATE: str.length
return 0;
}
```

When I run the program and don't type a `string` and press `Enter`, I get an `empty` output. Does that mean that the `while` loop ran and considered that there is an `input` even it was empty?

How can I terminate this loop?

Finally, why don't I get the `length` of the string in my output?

**UPDATE:** *I want to solve the issue using `string` functions*

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will get a `compile Time Error`. What is s?

Comment: @Javed Akram. I modified `s`, but the question remaons valid. Thanks

Comment: I figured the issue. It seems that I forgot to insert { } around the **two** `std::cout` statements. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because "enter" produces "carrier return" symbol. It is invisible and just starts the new line.
You can use an istream object and use get() function, which return the number of characters read:

char ch;

while(cin.get(ch))
{
}

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that using `string` functions? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but get() from istream doesn't accept strings. You can look at the reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/  But I can advice you to call string.push_back(ch); call in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code this way and set a breakpoint in line 4:

```
  std::string str;
  while (std::cin >> str)
  {
    std::cout << "you typed: " << str << "\n";
    std::cout << "str.length(): " << str.length() << "\n";;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop, `std::cin>>str` will return `true` if `std::cin` successfully read data into `str`, else it will return `false`.

Since `std::cin` can always read data from the input stream, that means, `while(std::cin >> str)` will be an infinite loop, unless you press some key that generates EOF character. The combination of keys that produces EOF, depends on OS.There is one more thing that can produce EOF, which is if you close the input stream!

Answer (score 0):

The input:

```
std::cin>>str
```

Reads one **[white]** space separated word from the stream.
White space include (space/tab and new line).

This means it ignores all white space until it gets a non-white space character. It then reads characters until it gets a white space character.

Thus if you just hit newline (enter) it will ignore the character. It keeps ignoring until it gets to a word.

If you want to make the loop finish. You have two choices. Look for a special word. Or inject an EOF character into the stream. On Unix/Linux this is done with <ctrl>-D on WIndows <ctrl>-Z